# how d I install the phonegap contacts plugin?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

[image]I've installed the plugin via command line to my phonegap project and i can see the files have been included in the plugin directory, but do i also have to include the javascript files in my index.html file just like a web app or do the js files automatically get linked? Does anyone know that answer to this as I've found little to no documentation.

[image]

[image]

So it appears to have copied over the plugin folder to the plugin directory itself and i can see the ios.json file in the plugin directory that's supposed to write the feature entry to the xml file but: there is no entry anywhere in the xml file and the .h and .m files did not get installed anywhere either. Manually putting:

```
<feature name="Contacts">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts" />
</feature>
```

in the xml file and this did nothing. I've also tried manually copying the .h and .m files to the platforms/ios/plugin directory and this did nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I figured this out:

1. You need to delete platforms/ios and platforms plugins/ios.json before you install any plugins and before you build ios to make sure everything build correctly so if you've already build ios and then you want to install a plugin go delete those two items first
2. Then run your command line install of the plugin
3. The plugin will only put the correct files in the correct place if you did number 1 also it will write the feature module to the config.xml file but if you are using phonegap 3.x it will write it to the wrong one see 4
4. It writes to the config file located at platforms/ios/(projectName) config.xml NOT platforms/ios/www/config.xml and not www/config.xml <---- this last one is where it should write to because it will override all config files in platforms when you build. So before you build ios again go grab the modules it wrote to platforms/ios/(projectName)/config.xml and paste them into www/config.xml or they will be overwritten when you do "build ios"

now your plugin will work...

Comment: I gave you a +1.  Can I give cordova -1?  This breaks the whole model that the developer can mixin new plugins at will.

Answer (score 0):

Once you added the plugin through the command line there is no need to include any js seperately.
To check if your plugins are added in your project,you can just refer if the cofig.xml file has the entry for the plugin you hav installed.

For more information on config.xml refer

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/config_ref_index.md.html

This file is located at different loction for different platforms.

For example for android it is located at folder

app/platforms/android/assets/www/config.xml

If you shift your project to SDK,after creating from command line,..you should refer config file under directory

app/platforms/android/res/www/config.xml

If config has the plugin entry,then it means plugin is integrated with your project.

Cordova has reference to this config file and links it with our project

Comment: I've installe via command line and moved the CDVcontacts.h and .m files to ios plugins folder and i get this when i run my app in the ios sim: 2014-04-10 23:39:43.670 kontax[5886:60b] CDVPlugin class CDVContacts (pluginName: Contacts) does not exist.
2014-04-10 23:39:43.671 kontax[5886:60b] ERROR: Plugin 'Contacts' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.

Comment: If you have installed through command line there is no need to move the .h and .m files.Cordova refers to the default location.If you have moved it,the plugin file would not be found by cordova.Move it back to original place or remove plugin and reinstall it

Comment: I tried it before I moved it... and the result was the same there was no entry added anywhere in any config.xml file nor was any .h .m file moved accordingly... I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. The documentation for this is terrible and I really need to get this solved.

Comment: This is how i installed:
phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts

Comment: refer config under www directory...see the alternate answer

Comment: if its a cordova project command to add plugin is  cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.core.contacts.The syntax you use is phonegap plugin installation.Both will work differently due to variation in project structure eventhough phonegap is build on cordova.please check

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it again.If you are able to download the plugin into the plugin directory but config.xml does not have the entry for that plugin.Just add the reference manually into the config file.

Reference code is like this

```
<feature name="Contacts">
<param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts" />
</feature>
```

Now try running it..Cordova must be able to refer it

Directory for IOS config file

app/platforms/ios/www/config.xml

If you are running in xcode SDk then refer config under

pp/platforms/ios/app-name/config.xml

Comment: well what's weird is i can see in the plugins/ios.json it has the snippet it's supposed to add the the xml file but it's just not doing it {"prepare_queue":{"installed":[],"uninstalled":[]},"config_munge":{"framework":{"AddressBook.framework":{"true":1},"AddressBookUI.framework":{"true":1},"CoreGraphics.framework":{"false":1}},"config.xml":{"/*":{"<feature name=\"Contacts\"><param name=\"ios-package\" value=\"CDVContacts\" /></feature>":1}}},"installed_plugins":{"org.apache.cordova.contacts":{"PACKAGE_NAME":"com.kontax.app"}},"dependent_plugins":{}}

Comment: I figured it out and wrote my own answer. It was a combo of a lot of issues.